Cypress .type does not update the v-model value in my form powered by Vue3
login.vue - which is the login page
<template>
  <v-container id="login-page">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <input id="username" v-model="username" data-cy="username" required />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script setup>
const username = ref()
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>

login.cy.js - my test file for the login page
describe('Login form', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/login')
  })

  it('Correct username and password results to successful login', () => {
    cy.get('#username').type('admin')
  })
})


With my test script, the v-model does not update and does not write anything on the input when the video is watched. When I removed the v-model attribute on login.vue it will work just fine.
What would be the appropriate cypress methods to make it work. Eventually, I will use that username to submit to an backend API. I just made optimized it with a username field since that is the particular main problem.

It worked ok when I tried it - how are you testing the submit mentioned in comments below? That may give some clue.

Simply just run cypress run. Then check the videos. It works when my <input> does not have a v-model attribute. I am basing on what I see on the videos, not really the test result

Try adding an assertion, it may be that the test is ending too soon, wrt to what is captured on the video.
cy.get('#username').type('admin')
cy.get('#username').invoke('val').should('eq', 'admin')

To confirm v-model updates, ideally you would have something else displayed on the page that uses the username variable, and you could assert that has the correct value.

I tried using wait like cy.wat(10000) and actually submitting the form. But the request results showed that the submitted data is empty

Waiting on an intercept on the submit would be better - everything you want to test should be in the test - including submit results.
